# Display does not hide

Tags: javascript, html, function

The problem it`s something in the function is not working, the html elemts I found(get elementByClass) and the addeventListener is working as well, so I want to know why is not working, it's maybe that "formSection.style.display = "block";" because it's not to recognize the code.

```js
let state = {
  menu: false,
};

let formSection = document.getElementsByClassName("form");
let formButton = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonMenu");

formButton[0].addEventListener("click", clickMenu);

function clickMenu() {
  if (state.menu == false) {
    formSection.style.display = "block";
    state.menu = true;
  } else {
    formSection.style.display = "none";
    state.menu = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonMenu">HIDE BUTTON</button>
<div class="form">
  <form id="registration-form" method="POST" action="MAILTO:@gmail.com" enctype="text/plain">
    <label class="label-form" for="email">Direccion de Correo:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-input" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Su correo electronico" />

    <label class="label-form" for="name">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-input" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Su nombre" />

    <label class="label-form" for="lastname">Apellido:</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-input" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Su apellido" />

    <label class="label-form" for="telephone">Telefono:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-input" id="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="Su telefono" />

    <button type="submit">Enviar Comentario!!</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: that is the error    Uncaught TypeError: formSection.style is undefined

Comment: `formSection` is a HTMLCollection, not a single element. Try `formSection[0]`

Comment: Try `let formSection = document.querySelector(".form");` - `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, whereas `querySelector` returns the first matching item

Comment: @Kinglish Your suggestion is good, but `getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Several things

- Your form selector gets a collection but why not use the form ID
- Toggle a class is much simpler - use ternary operator for convenience and readability
- let's also change the text of the button

```js
let formSection = document.getElementById("registration-form");
let formButton = document.querySelector(".buttonMenu"); // simpler than addressing an HTML collection

formButton.addEventListener("click", clickMenu);

function clickMenu() {
  formSection.classList.toggle("hide");
  formButton.textContent = formSection.matches(".hide") ? "SHOW FORM" : "HIDE FORM"
}
```

```css
.hide { display:none }
```

```html
<button class="buttonMenu">HIDE FORM</button>
<div class="form">
  <form id="registration-form" method="POST" action="MAILTO:@gmail.com" enctype="text/plain">
    <label class="label-form" for="email">Direccion de Correo:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-input" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Su correo electronico" />

    <label class="label-form" for="name">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-input" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Su nombre" />

    <label class="label-form" for="lastname">Apellido:</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-input" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Su apellido" />

    <label class="label-form" for="telephone">Telefono:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-input" id="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="Su telefono" />

    <button type="submit">Enviar Comentario!!</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) is going to return an `HTMLCollection`, so you'll need to do a similar `formSection[0]` to access the `style` attribute of the specific node.

You can look to use the relatively newer APIs for selectors, [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) (returns 1st matching element) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (returns all matching elements), which make the task a lot easier.

Also, look at [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) for managing classes on an element.

```js
let state = {
  menu: false,
};

let formSection = document.querySelectorAll(".form");
let formButton = document.querySelector(".buttonMenu");

formButton.addEventListener("click", clickMenu);

function clickMenu() {
  console.log(formSection.classList)
  if (!state.menu) {
    formSection.classList.remove('show')
    formSection.classList.add('hide')
    state.menu = true;
  } else {
    formSection.classList.remove('hide')
    formSection.classList.add('show')
    state.menu = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonMenu">HIDE BUTTON</button>
<div class="form">
  <form id="registration-form" method="POST" action="MAILTO:@gmail.com" enctype="text/plain">
    <label class="label-form" for="email">Direccion de Correo:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-input" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Su correo electronico" />

    <label class="label-form" for="name">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-input" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Su nombre" />

    <label class="label-form" for="lastname">Apellido:</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-input" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Su apellido" />

    <label class="label-form" for="telephone">Telefono:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-input" id="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="Su telefono" />

    <button type="submit">Enviar Comentario!!</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not vote down, but to have two classes and not just toggle one and also have two ifs for a boolean OP already is toggling is perhaps inelegant to some. I already suggested classList, but in a more elegant way, and perhaps that triggered a downvote

Comment: @mplungjan Fair enough, but that's not reason enough to downvote IMO (not targetted at you), not sure if optimizing a solution is an expectation.

Comment: I cannot NOT optimize. If I just wanted to give an answer, I would vote to close a typo-type or find a dupe

Comment: @mplungjan That's understandable from your perspective. Sometimes an answer to unblock OP should suffice, idk? Can't always make assumptions on the bigger problem when we see only a snippet of the code here. For instance, why not add an `id` to the form button as well? might as well optimize the HTML while we're at it, change from `type=text` to semantic types?

Comment: Sure but now he has both I’d and class selection and answer as to why the code failed are in the comments to the question

Comment: @mplungjan sure, that's still some level of selective optimization though, right? like leaving out some bits of what we would do differently if it was our codebase? Also, do you feel, just fixing the code to `formSection[0]` would have been a good answer?

Comment: Not as answer. It’s a comment and the question could be closed as dupe. I wanted to be a little more elegant but did not consider changing semantics

Comment: Fair enough, I guess :) Anyway, I'm fine with my answer not being the accepted answer or it not being upvoted even, but the downvote didn't (or still doesn't) make sense to me but that's okay! thanks for the talk :D